# Convert 12-hour time format to 24 hour as in mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, time

I wish to convert the time returned in array format in CakePHP to 24-hour format in MySQL.
Following is the code:

```
$this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime']
```

It returns:

```
array(
'hour' => '05',
'min' => '21',
'meridian' => 'am'
```

)

Now I wish to convert this to MySQL time format: `00:00:00` - 24 format so that I can retrieve records that match this particular time.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the FormHelper and your datatype on the `departure_time` field is either `DATETIME` or `TIME`, Cake will "automagically" handle all find and save operations properly.

So the fact that the actual data array holds separate `hour`, `min` and `meridian` fields doesn't impact the way it is stored in the database, this will convert nicely to `05:21:00` without any additional logic being necessary in your Model or Controller. If you want to find all records matching this time, you can simply find it with the full timestamp. Use something like:

```
$this->Rideoffer->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Rideoffer.departure_time' => '05:21:00'
    )
));
```

**Update**

In reply to your comment, if you want to use the inserted value immediately, convert it to a DateTime object and format that in your condition. For example:

```
$time =& $this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime'];
$date = new DateTime($time['hour'] . ':' . $time['min'] . ' ' . $time['meridian']);
```

Then format the date in your find:

```
$this->Rideoffer->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Rideoffer.departure_time' => $date->format('H:i:s')
    )
));
```

Comment: thanks, but when i match $this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime'] in condition, the records aren't matched. if i explicitly specify time like u said- '05:00:00', the records are returned. Why so?

Comment: @z22 Because `$this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime']` holds an array, rather than the string '05:00:00', so you can't directly use that as condition. See my updated answer for a way to get the value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

cakephp helpers [**dateFormat**](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-dateformat) will help you.

`dateformat option` will allow you to configure the date parts.

Comment: actually i have used it in view but my question is how do i retrieve its value in mysql format in controller?

Comment: means from database select Query.?